# Unlocked package is not fully deployed

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, package, unlocked-package, package-install

I have unlocked org-dependet package.
There are some layouts on org, for example:

Account- layout A,
Account- layout B,
Account- layout C,
Account- layout D,
Account- layout E

Then I retrieve theese layouts, do some changes (in each of them), and add them to package.
When I install package on org, some of layouts are updated, others are not. Why this can happen ?

Answer (score 2):

Layouts can't generally be updated by a package. That is to say, if the package creates a layout (or the first time it is incorporated into the package), the layout will be set as per the package specification, but further updates won't count. This is the same behavior as with Managed Packages. You would have to uninstall/reinstall the package for changes to take effect.

Comment: Is there any documentation for unlocked packages about it ?